# Not able to install qhull while importing tesseract in python

Tags: python-2.7, tesseract, qhull

I want to extract data from bunch of tables stored in the form of images -

While importing tesseract it prompts for the Qhull installation (as per the documentation http://pytesseract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials.html)

Code -

```
> import Image 
> from tesseract import image_to_string
> print image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')) print
> image_to_string(Image.open('test-english.jpg'), lang='eng')
```

I get following promt but I'm not able to input the directory correctly -

```
Please enter the path to an existing directory where qhull should be installed:
```

I tried giving directory in quotes, also through a variables but it keeps giving me invalid directory error

This should be pretty straight forward but I'm just not getting it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use `pytesseract` instead

```
pip install pytesseract
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You Need to change some lines of codes in
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\tesseract\voro.py file

in line after

    # Qhull installation 
    if config_parser.has_option('qhull','install-dir'):
        _qhulldir = config_parser.get('qhull','install-dir').strip()
    else:
    # Ask user for qhull directory
##    qstr = 'Please enter the path to an existing directory where qhull should be installed: 
        qstr = 'C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/tesseract'
    ##    _qhulldir = os.path.expanduser(raw_input(qstr).strip())
        _qhulldir = os.path.expanduser(qstr)
```

Comment: Please, also try to explain the answer and read [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)